# fadein div on android mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, iphone, fadein

I'm trying to display a div with content over a 360° panorama with javascript.
It works perfect on IE, Firefox, Safari, Iphone, Ipad and android 3 (tablet) but doesn't work as it should on android mobile (2.3.3).

From my panorama I call a javascript function to fadein a div wich has an absolute position and display:none.

Here is the javascript

```
function ouvrirDiv(divnum){
$('#wrapper'+divnum).fadeIn("slow");}
function fermerDiv(divnum){
    $('#wrapper'+divnum).fadeOut("slow");}
```

Here is my html

```
<div id="pano">
<noscript><table style="width:100%;height:100%;"><tr style="valign:middle;"><td><div style="text-align:center;">ERROR:<br/><br/>Javascript not activated<br/><br/></div></td></tr></table></noscript>


<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[

    var swf = createswf("nantes.swf", "krpanoSWFObject", "100%", "100%");
    swf.addVariable("xml", "nantes.xml");
    swf.addParam("wmode","opaque");
    swf.embed("pano");

// ]]>

    </script>
</div>



<div id="wrapper1"><div id="scroller">
<div class="closetop"><a href="javascript:" onClick="fermerDiv(1)">Fermer</a></div>
<div class="closebottom"><a href="javascript:" onClick="fermerDiv(1)">Fermer</a></div>
<div id="tabContainer1">
    <div class="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li id="tabHeader_1">Texte</li>
        <li id="tabHeader_2">Photos</li>
        <li id="tabHeader_3">Vidéos</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
<div class="tabscontent">

<div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_1">  
Texte...
</div>

<div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_2">
Photos...
</div>

<div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_3">
Videos...
</div>

</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 800px) { html { overflow:hidden; } }
        html { height:100%; }
        body { height:100%; overflow: hidden; margin:0; padding:0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000;   -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }

#pano {
width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
}

#wrapper1 , #wrapper2 , #wrapper3 , #wrapper4 , #wrapper5 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px; bottom:-60px; left:0px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    overflow:auto;
    display:none;
}

#scroller {
    position:relative !important; 
    margin:0 auto;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    width:100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    background:transparent;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Here is the behaviour on default android browser: the wrapper div is opened but stays behind the panorama.
On Opera mobile the panorama can't be scrolled until you call a wrapper div, but then the wrapper is over the pano (wich is correct) but you can't scroll it, you can scroll the panorama instead...

I have really no idea of the problem...
If someone has an idea, thanx very much !!!

MY TEST PAGE iS THERE : http://www.360images.fr/nantes/nantes.html

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem, too. For me adding

```
.hide()
```

before to

```
$('divelement').fadein
```

works.